# Mongoose Populate Virtuals not working and returning null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I read about [Mongoose Populate Virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) and thought that it was cool that it's similar to a join operation in SQL.

When I tried it on my app, it wouldn't work. My app is similar to this, only simplified

I have a Classroom and Teacher Schema in separate files

**Classroom.js**

```
...
...
var ClassroomSchema = new Schema({
   class_code:String,
   teacher_id:String
});

ClassroomSchema.virtual('teacher',{
   ref:'Teacher',             //model to reference
   localField:'teacher_id',   //Class.teacher_id
   foreignField:'teacher_id', //a Teacher.teacher_id
   justOne:true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Classroom',ClassroomSchema');
```

**Teacher.js**

```
***
***
var TeacherSchema = new Schema({
   name:String,
   teacher_id:String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Teacher',TeacherSchema);
```

in my **app.js**

```
var Classroom = require('Classroom.js');
var Teacher = require('Teacher.js');

//Find classrooms
Classroom.find({}).populate('teacher').exec(function(err,docs){
    if(err) throw err
    if(docs) console.log(docs);
});
```

It would then return classrooms but with the 'teacher' field equal to **null**

Am I missing something here? Why does it return null?

Comment: In which version of MongoDB are you testing?

Comment: Which version of mongoose are you using? I tried your code with `5.0.1` and it works. Also have you tried printing `docs[0].teacher` instead of `console.log(docs)` ? By default virtuals are skipped when inspecting/jsonifying objects.

Comment: MongoDB 3.6.3 and Mongoose 5.0.13. This isn't my actual app, just a simplification, my actual app has additional fields but its essentially the same. I'm just wondering what could be the reason why it isn't working. Should I post my actual app? It's pretty lengthy since it's supposed to be some kind of school system.   Also, I haven't tried printing it solo, I'll try.

Comment: I've tried console.log(docs[0].teacher) but it doesn't work, it produces an error 'cannot read property 'teacher' of undefined'.

Comment: If `justOne` is true, 'docs' will be a single doc as opposed to an array. `justOne` is false by default. In your case is 'true' so 'docs' is not an array. Try console.log(docs.teacher)

Comment: So I decided to re-write my code neatly, I got it working with printing docs[0].teacher and there was actually a mismatch on the names of the field in the Schema and the one in the actual collection in MongoDB . So another questions is, how do I print it with console.log(docs) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the toJson and toObject options to the Schema like this:

```
var ClassroomSchema = new Schema({
   class_code:String,
   teacher_id:String
},
{ toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true }});
```

Answer (score 0):

it didn't work on version after 5.2.18.
if set virtuals true you have only virtual fields and if set false you have virtual populate but not fields